# Antivirus cleans up the packaged executable from Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, executable, antivirus

I used [`electron-builder`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to package my Electron app into a single executable (I am working on a Windows machine, x64 architecture):

```
electron-builder build --win portable
```

However, my antivirus (Sophos Endpoint Agent) detects the `.exe` file in the `dist` directory as a threat, and deletes it. The antivirus outputs this message: `Generic ML PUA detected at [path_of_exe_file]`.

Interestingly, the `.exe` file located in the `dist\win-unpacked` directory does not get deleted by the antivirus, and I am able to run it.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Get a better antivirus.

Comment: First, you need to make sure you aren't accidentally bundling some dangerous code into your executable.  If you are 100% sure you aren't (probably confirmed by running it through other anti-virus programs), then most anti-virus programs can be configured to ignore certain directories (not scan them).  But, I'd agree with the earlier sentiment, it sounds like maybe you need a better anti-virus program that doesn't confuse your custom program with some virus.

Comment: I'm having same issue with VS .NET Core compilation :D